# Combining a get method with a register Observer method

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I am writing an application that uses the observer pattern. The client class needs to know  when an Employee object's state changes. It also needs to know the state of the employee at the current time (before any updates have been made). At the moment i am using a getEmployee() method and then registering an employee observer:

```
public class MyClass implements EmployeeObserver{

 ...

 Employee employee= subjectClass.getEmployee();

 subjectClass.registerEmployeeObserver(this);

 ... 

}
```

Is there anything wrong with combining these methods so that an Employee object is returned in the same method call that the observer is registered in? :

```
Employee employee = subjectClass.getAndObserveEmployee(this);
```

I know this may seem a bit strange, but i only need the getEmployee method when the observer class is initialised and the subjectClass already has quite a large interface that i want to keep to a minimum. So, is this acceptable or is it bad practice to combine two actions into a single method call?

Answer (score 0):

It's cleaner to separate the two.

On a separate note, why does the `Employee` itself not have an `addObserver()` method?  There could be a perfectly valid reason but that would be my first guess of where to find it if I were searching for it.  Either that or there would be some kind of service that manages employees and has the `addObserver(int employeeIdToObserver)` or something like that (implying that you already have a reference to the employee before you observer it.

Also, one way you could write the pattern is...

```
public interface EmployeeObserver {

    public void stateChanged(State oldState, State newState);

}
```

...for observers that need to know what the state was before the change.

Answer (score 0):

If sometimes you don't need the employee you have to do

```
subjectClass.getAndObserveEmployee(this);
```

which looks strange. or if sometimes you need emploee but not to register:

```
Employee employee = subjectClass.getAndObserveEmployee(null);
```

which again is not nice. If, let say you want to change the `register` part, (i.e. one more arg), you have to change the places where you use the function only for `get()` also.
I would not do that, except if necessary like in case of

```
oldVal = ConcurrentMap.replaceValue();
```

in this case *two operations* must be combined in one method because in concurrent system between two calls the state can change.